# Swift: How to set the height of cells automatically to be localized at the whole size of the screen

Tags: swift, uitableview, size, screen, cell

I would like to use the TableView with several cells, which use the whole screen size. How can I set it, to be like that? 
Now, when I choose the simulator with smaller screen it looks ok, but with heigher - there is a big space at the bottom.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: I arranged the cells at the VC and set the constraints of each element inside.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function to your table view VC implementation

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        return screenHeight
    }
```